# Any map $S^2 \times S^2 \to S^2$ is null-homotopic on one coordinate

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology, spheres, low-dimensional-topology

Prove that any map $f: S^2 \times S^2 \to S^2$ is null-homotopic on one coordinate, which is to say, either $f|: S^2 \times \left\{0\right\} \to S^2$ or $f|: \left\{0\right\} \times S^2 \to S^2$ is null homotopic.

I know this can be proved by considering the induced map on the cohomology ring $f^{\ast}: H^{\ast}(S^2)\to H^{\ast}(S^2\times S^2)$.

But I think there should be a more elementary way to prove this. Does anyone have an elementary proof simpler than the cohomology ring?

Comment: hi! I think the way that you suggest to prove this is actually really nice. What would constitute something more elementary? Or what is the flavor of argument that you are looking for

Comment: I'm actually curious how this result depends on the dimension.  Of course, the OP's proof works just as well in any even dimension, but leaves open the odd dimensional case.  The corresponding result is false for $S^1$, $S^3$, and $S^7$.  Viewing them as topological groups, taking $f$ to be the multiplication map gives a counterexample.    But what about $S^5$?

Comment: @xuxy Can you write your solution in detail?

Comment: @JasonDeVito for any odd $n$ consider the map $f:S^n\times S^n\rightarrow S^n$ given by $f(x,y)=y-2(x\cdot y)x$.  Then $(i)$ $f$ does have image in $S^n$, and $(ii)$ the restrictions of $f$ to the first and second factors are maps of degree $2$ and $-1$, respectively. In particular neither restriction is null homoptopic.

Comment: @Tyrone:  Oooh, that's clever, thanks!  In case anyone else wonders why "odd" is necessary to Tyrone's construciton, just note that $2$ is really $1+ (-1)^{n-1}$.

Comment: @Tyrone Wonderful example!

Comment: @AndresMejia: I'm looking for some direct geometric observation for this proposition.

Comment: @BobDobbs Consider $f^*(x)^2$ where $x$ generates $H^2(S^2)$.